# Url not found in server

Tags: django

I have written a function on paypal when user would cancel payment then it would redirect to `paypal-cancel` page which i have defied in my app level url.py. But problem is it is showing error that

```
Not Found
The requested URL /paypal-cancel was not found on this server.
```

BuT I have defined this function in url.

web/urls.py

```
  urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^paypal-payment$', ApiPaymentPayPalView.as_view(), name='paypal-payment'),
        url(r'paypal-cancel', PaypalCancelView.as_view(), name='paypal-cancel'),
]
```

whatever i do `r'paypal-cancel'` or `r'^paypal-cancel$'` nothing is working

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('web.urls')),
]
```

So,where am i doing wrong? I think i have given wrong regex probably!

Comment: Is `'web'` the `app` here? (since you specify `app/urls.py`

Comment: yes,sir @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: It would be a good idea to add `^` and `$` to the regex, e.g. `r'^paypal-cancel$'`. Having said that, the URLs you have shown should match `/paypal-cancel`. Are you sure that PayPal is redirecting to the correct domain, and that the error message is coming from Django. If you have debug mode enabled, the yellow Django error page will give a list of the URL patterns it tried, which can be useful to debug the problem.